# How to suppress -mmax value exceeded.Automatically increasing from old value to new value.<5409>?

Tags: openedge

> in prokb,its mentioned 
>       In 10.0B02 and above, the client session startup parameter -noincrwarn  was reintroduced 
>        to allow the selective suppression of the above four warning messages ONLY.  Since the
>       execution of the  4GL statement: SESSION:SUPPRESS-WARNINGS = YES. suppresses ALL warning
>       messages during the session.
>       Where and how could i set i this startup parameter -noincrwarn to suppress this warning 
>       message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"SESSION:SUPPRESS-WARNINGS = YES." doesn't do much of anything useful.  Or at least it didn't the last time I tested it.

The -mmax warning is harmless.  It is a "soft" limit that is dynamically allocated and expanded as needed.  You can ignore it.  Or if the .lg file entries really bother you, you can simply increase it to a reasonable value.  I routinely set it to 8192 for character sessions, 32768 for Windows.  The default, as JensD says, is ludicrously low.

Startup parameters, such as -noincwarn, can set in a number of ways:

1) Via the command line.  If your application starts via a script it will eventually invoke progress via "pro", "mpro", progress, prowin32, proapsv or some other executable (you can potentially link your own objects and create custom executables...)  The command line that invokes Progress will have a number of parameters.  You could add it there.  Windows example:

```
@echo off
set DLC=\Progress\OpenEdge
%DLC%\bin\prowin32 -db mydb -p start.p -noincwarn
```

(On windows it is also common for the shortcut properties to have the command line listed.)

2) In a "pf" file.  "PF" files are parameter files.  They contain a list of parameters in a text file.  This  makes it easy to share and manage parameters between many scripts.  To use a parameter file you need at least one -pf filename.pf parameter.  Unix example:

```
#!/bin/sh

DLC=/usr/dlc
export DLC

${DLC}/bin/_progres -db mydb -pf mypf.pf
```

Where "mypf.pf" might contain:

```
# mypf.pf
-p start.p
-noincwarn
```

There is a **global** .pf file in the Progress install directory called startup.pf.  You could also add it to that.

3) In an "ini file".  Sort of like the pf file but more complicated.  Indicated by the -ininame startup parameter.  Can also be influenced by registry keys.

Answer (score 0):

Why not removing or trying another value for -mmax? If you're moving from an old version of Progress it might be that -mmax is set very low.

> The Maximum Memory (-mmax) client session parameter specifies the maximum amount of memory allocated for r-code segments, in kilobytes.

Source: http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P11351?popup=true

Large memory consumption might depend on complicated business logic (things like very large and or deeply nested procedures) so you might consider looking into that.

However a much easier fix would be to increase the value. Default is 3096, meaning each client "only" gets 3 Mb for this. Not a very large amount with today's standards.

If you really only want to suppress the message. Set -noincrwarn in your client side startup script (or corresponding .pf-file/startup.pf).

Comment: Jensd, is there any command to find current -mmax value and how to set this value?

Comment: MESSAGE SESSION:STARTUP-PARAMETERS VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.

Answer (score 0):

Hosting a WPF element (windows Presentation Foundation) in an OpenEdge application can cause application to crash if any message cover the window. It is also the case of this message.

In order to suppress any messages including message 5409 ()
According to article "HOW TO SUPPRESS WARNING MESSAGES (5407),(5408),(5409),(5410) FROM DISPLAYING ON CLIENT SCREENS."

I used with expected results SESSION:SUPPRESS-WARNINGS = YES. As the first line in the starting procedure of the aplication.
Using -noincrwarn as the session startup parameter had no effect in Open Edge 11.4

Supress openedge messages:
http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P79795?popup=true

.NET related error for OpenEdge-WPF hibrid application "Invisible or disabled control cannot be activated"
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/e8cf6431-2a59-4335-8b36-fc8f35083823/invisible-or-disabled-control-cannot-be-activated?forum=winforms